# Firestore security rules, get function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Working with security rules, will it be faster to send some data about user in a token, or it doesn't matter and we are quietly able to use a `get` function without getting a doubled amount of requests to a database?
For example:

```
User {
  name;
  role;
}
```

1. Data in token

```
match <route> {
  allow write: if request.auth.token.role in [<roles...>];
}
```

2. No data in token

```
match <route> {
  allow write: if get(<pathToUserDoc>).data.role in [<roles...>];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the same information in the user token is always going to be faster and cheaper, as it avoids having to look up the value in a document for each user.